# F# Giraffe simple model validation based on attributes

Tags: f#, f#-giraffe

F# Giraffe provides it own validation mechanism different from standard ASP.net attributed based one.
So how can I use attribute based validation in Giraffe if it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Here answer from github
https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/issues/436

```
 open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    open System.Collections.Generic;

    let validateDataAnnotations (object:obj) =
        let ctx = new ValidationContext(object)
        let errors = new List<ValidationResult>()
        if Validator.TryValidateObject(object, ctx, errors, true) then None
        else Some errors
```